# Telegram Bot PHP Create Dynamic Buttons

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I am creating a manager bot that lists all admins of a certain channel or all managers of the bot or all the channels that bot have access to them ...

so i created a database and succesfully connected to it from the bot

what i'm going to do is : i.e i am the bot's manager so i send "panel" for the bot and it shows me the channels , the admins , more settings

when i click on the admins i want my bot to search through my admins table in data  base and for each username in db , create a button

i.e i have 5 admins in the table .. i want bot to create 5 diffrent buttons ( 'text' = admin['username']) and when i touch a button , it simply show me admin's information.....

so how could i create buttons ??

```
<?php
define ('API_KEY','MY_BOT_TOKEN');
//----######------

function makereq($method,$datas=[]){
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".API_KEY."/".$method;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($datas));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_error($ch)){
var_dump(curl_error($ch));
}else{
return json_decode($res);
}
}
//---------
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
var_dump($update);
//=========
$chat_id = $update->message->chat->id;
$message_id = $update->message->message_id;
$from_id = $update->message->from->id;
$name = $update->message->from->first_name;
$contact = $update->message->contact;
$cnumber = $update->message->contact->phone_number;
$cname = $update->message->contact->first_name;

$photo = $update->message->photo;
$video = $update->message->video;
$sticker = $update->message->sticker;
$file = $update->message->document;
$music = $update->message->audio;
$voice = $update->message->voice;
$forward = $update->message->forward_from;

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","id2056593_root","123456","id2056593_botdb");
$username = $update->message->from->username;
$textmessage = isset($update->message->text)?$update->message->text:'';
$reply = $update->message->reply_to_message->forward_from->id;
$stickerid = $update->message->reply_to_message->sticker->file_id;
//-----------
if($textmessage == "panel" || $textmessage == "Panel"){
    var_dump(makereq('sendMessage',[
                'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
                'text'=>"Welcome to the pannel",
                        'parse_mode'=>'MarkDown',
                'reply_markup'=>json_encode([
                    'keyboard'=>[
                    [
                       ['text'=>"Channels"],['text'=>"Admins"]
                    ],
                                    [
                                        ['text'=>"More Settings"]
                                    ]
                    ],
                    'resize_keyboard'=>true
                ])
                ]));
                }elseif($textmessage == "Channels"){
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM channels";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                            $text = "channel id :\n";
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $keyboard =json_encode([
                                'keyboard'=>[
                                    [
                                         ['text'=>"$row[username]"]
                                    ]]]);

                                                    }
                                                    makereq('sendMessage',[
                                                                        'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
                                                                        'text'=>"Pick up one channel from above",
                                                                        'reply_markup'=>$keyboard]
                                                                    );


                }elseif($textmessage == "Admins"|| $textmessage =="admins"){
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        $keyboard =json_encode([
                                'keyboard'=>[
                                    [
                                         ['text'=>"$row[username]"]
                                    ]]]);
                    }
                    makereq('sendMessage',[
                                        'chat_id'=>$update->message->chat->id,
                                        'text'=>"Pick up one admin",
                                        'reply_markup'=>$keyboard]
                                    );

                }
```

NOTE : My code just shows me ONE admin or ONE channel

P.S : I don't use Telegram-bot-php

Answer (score 0):

In your code in while loop you replace the $keyboard variable.
Try to change your code:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $keyboard =json_encode([
         'keyboard'=>[
               [
                  ['text'=> "$row[username]"]
               ]]]);
    }
```

by the below code:

```
$keyboard = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $keyboard[] = [
                  ['text'=> $row[username]]
               ];
}
$reply_markup  = json_encode(['keyboard'=> $keyboard]);
```